# passing struct in function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I spend lot of time to pass a struct pointer in a function. everything in the code is working only I couldn't figure out how to pass a struct in a function then I can do some operation inside a function. can you explain where exactly i'm fail and how to fix it? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i=0;
int* i_ptr=&i;
int count(int q);
int line_count();

struct student {
    int st_id;
    char st_name[20];
    int st_age;
    char st_dep[7];
    float st_grade;
};

int sort_student(struct student line[i],int i)
{
    printf("%f",line[1].st_grade);
    printf("   %s",line[1].st_name);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    /* struct loading from the file operation goes  here */
    int x=0;
    int i=line_count();
    struct student line[i];
    char file_line[100];
    char* line_parts;

    FILE * fp;
    if ((fp = fopen (file.txt", "r")) != NULL)
    {
        while (x<i) {
            if(fgets(file_line,100,fp) != NULL);     // gets line from the file.
            {
                line_parts = strtok(file_line,","); // breaks the line
                line[x].st_id  = atoi(line_parts);  // conversition string to int

                line_parts = strtok(NULL, ",");
                strcpy(line[x].st_name,line_parts);

                line_parts = strtok(NULL, ",");
                line[x].st_age = atoi(line_parts);

                line_parts = strtok(NULL, ",");
                strcpy(line[x].st_dep,line_parts);

                line_parts = strtok(NULL, ",");
                line[x].st_grade = atoi(line_parts);
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    sort_student(&line[i],i);
    return 0;
}

int line_count () //counts the number of line in the file, while loading the program.
{
    FILE * fp;         // file open from here.
    int i=0;
    int c;
    if ((fp = fopen ("/Users/rishav/Desktop/try/try/file.txt", "r")) != NULL)
    {
        while ((c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if (c=='\n') {
                i++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else printf("file reading Error.\n");
    return i;
}

int count(q)     // keeps track of i
{
    if(q==1)
    {
        (*i_ptr)++;
    }
    return *i_ptr;
}
```

Comment: You have a global variable called `i` but you `shadow` this declaration by having other variables called `i` - e.g. your loop iterator in `line_count`. Is this why you have `i_ptr`? A better solution would be to change the name of the global, call it `g_i` (g_ for global) or `s_i` if it is static.

Comment: is that the problem not passing struct in the function or that is another issue?

Comment: Another issue, hence a comment not an answer.

Comment: One major problem is here: `sort_student(&line[i],i);` because the `line` array has just `i` elements in it. Maybe you meant `sort_student(&line[0], i);` or just `sort_student(line, i);`?  You also have a problem with `if(fgets(file_line,100,fp) != NULL);` — the semicolon is unwanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `sort_student` function definition to

```
int sort_student(struct student* line,int i) {
    printf("%f",line->st_grade);
    printf("   %s",line->st_name);

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I change that and it display error that "must use struct tag to refer to type 'student'". on int sort_student(student* line,int i) ?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the array address to the first element and then find out which element? Plus what I see is you allocate `i` elements for your array and pass the `i` element which gives you seg fault.

Comment: @Rishav In C, you need to precede your typename with `struct` or use a `typedef`. just replace `student*` with `struct student*`.

Comment: @Farzad i remove [i] while pass the struct (i.e. sort_student(&line).Finally it work. but there is an error displaying in the same line "incompatible pointer types passing 'struct student(*)[i]' to parameter of type 'struct student*" what is this issue and is there any way i can fix this too?

Comment: @Rishav it really depends which element address you want to pass to your function. `&line[i]` sends the address of `i`th element of `line` array to your function. If you want to pass the starting (first) element address, you better change your `sort_student` function defintion to `int sort_student(struct student*) {}` and do `sort_student(line);`.

Comment: @Rishav when you remove `[i]`, you're actually sending the pointer to array starting element address.